# Elasticsearch gives parse error on tab character

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting parse errors trying to insert a document that contains a "\t" into elasticsearch.

Here's the least YAML:

A: '\t'

PLAY says "Got unexpected response. Sorry :("

This must be already answered, but can't find anything.

Comment: escape ` \ ` with another ` \ `.

Comment: Did you try that out?  Surprisingly, it still throws the error.  Other space characters don't.  So \n works fine.  Try throwing "A: '\\t'" into play and see what you get.

Comment: _Where_ are you specifying `A: '\t'`? You mention Play, so are you using the Play framework? Please show the actual request.

Comment: @pickypg I am using the PLAY interface on found.no.  I just put in exactly that string (A: '\t') as the document and hit RUN.  It gives me the vague error "unexpected results".  When I change '\t' to '\n' it runs fine.

Comment: This looks like a quirk with the site. Switching it over to JSON has the same issue.